# node:js TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-modules

hi m getting this error how can I fix it, m using ejs as a view engine,,,,,and in colsole at end it showa this in red line "[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

app.js

```
    var express = require('express');
    var createError = require('http-errors');
    var path = require('path');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
    var session = require('express-session');
    // var flash = require('req-flash');
    var cors = require('cors');
    var config = require('./config/config');
    var glob = require('glob');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    mongoose.connect(config.db);
    var db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('error', () => {
      throw new Error('unable to connect to database at ' + config.db);
    });

    var models = glob.sync(config.root + '/app/models/*.js');
    models.forEach(function (model) {
      require(model);
    });

    var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
    var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

    var app = express();

    app.use(cors())

    // view engine setup
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(fileUpload());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


    app.use(session({
        secret: 'nuerficnutrhgxmdshgjhf',
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true
    }));


    // Global variables
    app.use(function(req, res, next){
        res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
        res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
        res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
        next();
    });

    //DB connection start
    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/crud', {useNewUrlParser:         
    true})
    .then(() => console.log('connection successful'))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err))
    //DB Connection End


    app.use('/index', indexRouter);
    app.use('/', usersRouter);


    module.exports = require('./config/express')(app, config);

    app.listen(config.port, () => {
      console.log('Express server listening on port ' + config.port);
    });
```

Comment: could you post your router file say `./routes/users`

Comment: @1565986223  ./routes/users     paste.ofcode.org/7smKKUL55758uWGzkir9Nj

Comment: the file you've linked look alright

Answer (score 0):

What i found after running your App.js on my project is that `module.exports = require('./config/express')(app, config);` this line cause problem. I have turn this into `module.exports = { app }` and server run successfully.

I'm sharing my project App.js as an example. May be this help you keep your App.js in best way.

```
require('./config/config');
require('./config/mongoose');
const express = require('express');
const routes = require('./routes/index');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const {port, publicPath} = require('./config/port');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(publicPath));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

routes.forEach(function(route) {
    let controller = require(route);
    app.use("/", controller);
});

app.listen(port , () => {
    //eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
})

module.exports = {app};
```

Comment: no no I have already check it this is an old version and m using new version

Comment: Ok, let me check then.

Comment: @dev can you share a screenshot of your error. It will be help full.

Comment: Can you share one of the router file too? ('./routes/index')

Comment: Just a question: Why to export the app in app.js. For which purpose?

Comment: @kmgt good point. I have check it out and there is no need to export the app in this case. I haven't found a case yet where we need to export the app. I will update if i found anything like that.

Comment: sorry to say that m new to it and following some tutorials ,,, now I have changed that file into module.exports = { app } but still same error

Comment: route file users.js      paste.ofcode.org/7smKKUL55758uWGzkir9Nj

Comment: @dev try to comment all the app.use and open it one by one you will find out where the problem is occuring.